# Using event trigger how to pass the value to function on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check the input value, in case the value is null, then i would like to set the value as 1. and whenever the input element value changes, i require a event trigger...

i tried here, but it's not working. what is wrong with my code or what is the correct way to do this?

here is my code :

```
var page = function () {
    return {
        init : function () {
            var input = $("#pNo");
            $(document).on("pageChange", this.onPageChange.bind(this));
            $.event.trigger({type: "pageChange", element:input});
            $(this.pageInput).bind("change paste keyup", $.event.trigger({type: "pageChange"}));
        },

        onPageChange : function (e) {
            // from the e i would like to select input value...
        }
    }
}();

page.init();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jyfgw7L/)

**Update :**

//This is works on page load..

```
var page = function () {
    return {
        init : function () {
            var input = $("#pNo");
            $(input).val(1).trigger('pageChange');
            $(document).on("pageChange", this.onPageChange.bind(this));
            $(this.pageInput).bind("change paste keyup", $.event.trigger({type: "pageChange"}));
        },

        onPageChange : function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}();

page.init();
```

Comment: I don't see what `this.pageInput` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use .change() and wrap your function in there or call your trigger.

```
$("#pNo").change(function(){
 if($(this).val() == ""){
   $(this).val("1");
 }
 //your function to be triggered on change
}
```

Comment: How would a value set to nothing become null?

Comment: no way it is null (besides being an empty select) but the question stated "in case the value is null" so I went for that